# MySQL Getting around error 1093

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

Error 1093 states that you can't UPDATE or DELETE using a subquery if your subquery queries the table you are deleting from.

So you can't do

```
delete from table1 where id in (select something from table1 where condition) ;
```

Ok, what's the best way to work around that restriction, (assuming you really do need to subquery to perform the delete and cannot eliminate the self referencing subquery entirely?)

Edit:

Here's the query for those who are interested:

```
mysql> desc adjacencies ;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| parent  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| child   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pathLen | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+



-- The query is going to
-- tell all my children to
-- stop thinking my old parents
-- are still their parents

delete from adjacencies
where parent in 
(
-- ALL MY PARENTS,grandparents
  select parent
  from adjacencies
  where child=@me
  and parent!=@me
)

-- only concerns the relations of my
-- grandparents WHERE MY CHILDREN ARE CONCERNED
and child in
(
  -- get all my children
  select child
  from adjacencies
  where parent=@me
)

;
```

So what I've tried so far is creating a temporary table called `adjsToDelete`

```
create temporary table adjsToRemove( parent int, child int ) ;
insert into adjsToRemove...
```

So now I have a collection of relations to delete, where the parent/child pairs each uniquely identify a row to delete.  But *how do I delete each **pair*** from the adjacencies table now?

It seems I need to add a unique `auto_increment`ed key to each entry in `adjacencies`, is that right?

Comment: did you try doing with nolock?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the query?

Comment: The answer by a1ex07 (delete with joins) will perform better on large tables than the workarounds using double-nested subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery`
- [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

You just cannot **cannot specify target table for delete**

one of my workaround : [MySQL DELETE FROM with subquery as condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition/4471350#4471350)

Comment: So it looks like I will need an ID column in my adjacencies table like 'create table adjacencies( id int PRIMARY KEY, parent int, child int, pathLen int )` -- I cannot do this solution otherwise - right?

Comment: @bobobobo - Yes, you can create an extra column, and update it with the ID that matched,and delete if the extra column contains **NON-ZERO** value. **Or** create a snapshot table contains all the ID. I would prefer method two, as it did not touch on current working data.

Answer (score 8):

A workaround, found in http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6980, that worked for me is to create an alias to the sub query that will return the items. So

```
delete from table1 where id in 
  (select something from table1 where condition)
```

would be changed to

```
delete from table1 where id in
  (select p.id from (select something from table1 where condition) as p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
delete t1,t2 
FROM  table1 t1  
INNER JOIN 
table1 t2 ON (t2.something = t1.id);
```

For the query in the question, this should be equivalent:

```
delete A
from adjacencies A
join adjacencies B ON A.parent = B.parent AND B.child=@me AND B.parent != @me
join adjacencies C ON A.child = C.child AND C.parent=@me
```

Comment: You can use Inner Join on delete.

Comment: So can someone clarify how this response can be used to perform the subquery listed in the question?

Comment: Untested, but something like `DELETE a1 FROM adjacencies AS a1 INNER JOIN adjacencies AS a2
ON a1.id=a2.id
WHERE a1.parent=a2.parent and a2.child=@me and a2.parent!=@me;`

Comment: @a1ex07 I've updated with an (untested) example of how this solves the original query

Answer (score 1):

Simplified:

```
-- Collect ids
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cleanup_lookup AS 
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE condition;

-- Delete the selected records
DELETE t FROM table1 t INNER JOIN cleanup_lookup l ON t.id = l.id;

-- Temporary tables get dropped when the connection is closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one without hesitation.

Your query:

```
delete from table1 
where id in (select something from table1 where condition);
```

Updated query:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * 
             FROM 
                 (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table1 GROUP BY Column2) x);
```

Here `Column2` is column on which you want to find duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE FROM `table1` 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * 
             FROM 
                 (select max(`id`)FROM table1 group by Column2 having count(*) >1) x);
```

Here Column2 is a column on which you want to find duplicate records (it may have multiple columns).

This will delete only duplicate records.