# mysql automatically prevent redundant inserts

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table like

```
create table adjacencies(
  relationId int not null primary key auto_increment,
  parent int not null,
  child int not null,
  pathLen int not null
) ;
```

I'm inserting large amounts of entries like

```
insert into adjacencies( parent, child, pathLen )
select a, b, c from something where condition ;
```

So sometimes when I run my insert query, its possible that a (parent,child) relation will already exist and be duplicated.  Bad news.

I don't want to create a primary key on ( parent, child ) because that results in a hard fail (query failure).

What I want is a **soft fail** if there is an attempt to insert a (parent, child) pair that already exists in the table (i.e only that pair gets *ignored*, and the rest of the query proceeds normally).

What's the best way to do this in MySQL?

(* Wondering [why is there a relationId member in this table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484779/mysql-getting-around-error-1093))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite unique key around the parent and child columns.  Then issue a query like this instead:

```
insert ignore into adjacencies( parent, child, pathLen )
select a, b, c from something where condition ;
```

The `IGNORE` clause will turn duplicate key errors into warnings.

Comment: I was faster but still have no any upvotes :'-( **UPD**: tie is good in such case :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
INSERT IGNORE ...
```

and create unique index/primary key

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

(c) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html