# Update query, how to get column name from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know if it's possible but this is what I want:

```
UPDATE `tbl_users` SET (SELECT `category` FROM `tbl_items` WHERE id = ?) = (SELECT `item` FROM `tbl_items` WHERE id = ?) WHERE id = ?
```

but this isn't possible I get this error in PHP:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in.

I want to update a column from tbl_users which name of the column is in tbl_items.

Comment: Just explain what you want using this query?

Comment: How `User` table and `Category` table related to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question, but could you do the first query then use the results of that query to do the second one? so:

```
"SELECT `category`, `item` FROM `tbl_items` WHERE `id`=?"
```

Then use the results for (assuming the row is held in `$row`):

```
"UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `".$row['category']."` = '".$row['item']."' WHERE `id`=?
```

Comment: you did understand it :) but i already knew that, that will work but is it possible to do it in 1 statement?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can only use a subquery to set the value, not to idenfity the column. So `column = (SUBQUERY)` but not `(SUBQUERY) = (SUBQUERY)`

Comment: Thanks ! I will use your option

Comment: No worries :) have you seen these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588710/mysql-update-query-with-sub-query AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216591/mysql-sub-query-select-statement-inside-update-query

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in one statment. you dont need two queries and fetch and so on.

```
    UPDATE `tbl_users` 
    INNER JOIN `tbl_items`  ON `tbl_users`.id = `tbl_items`.id
    SET `tbl_items`.`category`  = `tbl_items`.`item` 
    WHERE `tbl_users`.id = ?
```