# I want to update a column if the row is duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table named `information`.

[image]

As you see in the previous table there is column named `number`, this column has a many duplicate values.

**What I want is, if the row is duplicate, update its `tab` cell to `1`, otherwise, leave it as it is `0`.**

The following is what I done.

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE information SET tab='1' WHERE number = (SELECT distinct number FROM information)");
```

Comment: Well, first try IN() instead of "=" (although there is considerable scope for further improvement) - and usual caveats about sql injection, deprecated functions, as well as the benefits of prepareed statements

Comment: Thanks about your warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE information
SET tab = '1'
WHERE number IN (SELECT number
                 FROM (SELECT number
                       FROM information
                       GROUP BY number
                       HAVING count(*) > 1
                      ) AS temp)
```

The subquery will return all duplicated `number` values.

Edit: I've tried it and MySQL shows 1093 error. I have just edited the query according to the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550260/1852787).

Comment: I have applied your query, but there is no update happened. `tab` column still `0`.

Comment: Can you run the subquery alone and see the results? In the case of image above, it should return 2 rows (157, 300).

Comment: `it should return 2 rows (157, 300).`> Yes.

Comment: Edited the query. The original query was raising a MySQL error due to you cannot select a table that you are updating. Please test it again, it should work now with this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with an `update` and `join`:

```
UPDATE information i join
       (select number
        from information i
        group by number
        having count(*) > 1
       ) idups
       on i.number = idups.number
    SET i.tab = '1';
```