# Update column based on min number with status column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update number 2 with status = 8

```
UPDATE tqueue 
SET status = '8' 
WHERE (SELECT MIN(number) 
       FROM tqueue
       WHERE STATUS IN ('4')
         AND get_ticket >= CURDATE( ) 
         AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
       GROUP BY service)
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
number   |    status   |  get_ticket 
--------------------------------------------------
   3            4         2017-02-18  13:43:01
   2            4         2017-02-18  12:34:03
   1            8         2017-02-18  10:04:59
```

Comment: `update tqueue set status = 8 where number = 2`.  Please explain if this solves your problem or why not

Comment: update your question in a consistent wya .. you refer to column and condition that are not in you sample and in your explanation ..

Comment: when every time i update the data min number with status 4 will change to status 8 not only number 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for updating min `number` in `status=8` into `status=4` ?

Try this one:

```
 SELECT @mynumber:=number FROM tqueue
 WHERE STATUS = '4'
 AND get_ticket >= CURDATE( )
 AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 1 DAY )
 GROUP BY service
 order by number asc
 limit 0,1 ;

 UPDATE tqueue SET status = '8' where number = @mynumber ;
```

Also, you can use temporary table for update self-reference:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytbl_numbers AS 
 SELECT number FROM tqueue
 WHERE STATUS = '4'
 AND get_ticket >= CURDATE( )
 AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 1 DAY )
 GROUP BY service
 order by number asc
 limit 0,1 ;

 UPDATE tqueue SET status = '8' where number in (SELECT * FROM  mytbl_numbers) ;
```

More useful Answers may be found at [[+]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484779/mysql-getting-around-error-1093) & [[+]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition/4471350#4471350) & ...

Comment: it's error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'tqueue' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, we cannot use one table for target and source table in `update` and `delete`. So I changed code, does it solves?