# Cannot delete from same table in subquery from

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

I know this argument has been addressed in this site many times, I just can't find a working solution, so I thought i would post my specific case to you, maybe you can help me...

I have a festival from which I need to eliminate the songs that got less than the 20% of the average evaluation of the night before.

I tried with this:

```
DELETE FROM concorre AS C 
WHERE C.dataSer='2014-02-24' 
AND C.votoTot<(SELECT AVG(B.votoTot) 
               FROM concorre AS B 
               WHERE B.dataSer='2014-02-23')/5
```

It resolves the "same table problem" but still gives me an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS C WHERE C.dataSer='2014-02-24' AND C.votoTot<(SELECT AVG(votoTot) FROM concor' at line 1

Comment: As your sub-query is going to return the same value for all entries have you considered using a parameter, this will remove the error relating to the sub query and potentially improve performance.

Comment: You shouldnt use `AS` when naming tables. Thats when you name columns you can make use of `AS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE c FROM concorre C 
JOIN (SELECT AVG(B.votoTot) average FROM concorre B WHERE B.dataSer='2014-02-23') d
WHERE C.dataSer='2014-02-24' 
AND C.votoTot < d.average /5
```

Comment: your query works, thank you very much, but I don't get what "DELETE c " means... what is c

Comment: It's for an exam so i need to be sure i understand every particular of it

Comment: c is the name of the table that you are deleting from. Since you join on more than 1 table, you need to indicate which table you delete from. `DELETE c FROM concorre C`. `DELETE FROM concorre c` will fail as there is more than 1 table in the delete statement. But `DELETE c` indicates which table to delete from that matches the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not allow a table that is being updated/deleted in the outer query to be selected from in any sub-query of the statement.

Here you are deleting from `concorre` table and also referring the same table in sub-query.

You can try something like this : [MySQL DELETE FROM with subquery as condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition/4471350#4471350)