# Subquery fails in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I have a subquery as follows : which will select the id's  according to   the condition first and delete

the records ,

```
    Delete from post_master_user_map WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM `post_master_user_map` WHERE posted_by_user_id=110);
```

But it gives me the following error :

```
You can't specify target table 'post_master_user_map' for update in FROM clause
```

What is wrong with this ? thanks in advance .

**UPDATE**

This also fails , I dont why

```
DELETE FROM `post_master_user_map` WHERE `reshare_id` in (SELECT id FROM `post_master_user_map` WHERE 
posted_by_user_id=110);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to modify a table and select from the same table in sub query.

Anyway to solve that error change your query as follows

```
Delete from post_master_user_map WHERE posted_by_user_id=110;
```

For the updated query(in your question) use following

```
    DELETE t1 FROM post_master_user_map as t1 INNER JOIN 
post_master_user_map as t2 ON t1.reshare_id=t2.id and t2.posted_by_user_id=110
```

Comment: DELETE FROM `post_master_user_map` WHERE `reshare_id` in (SELECT id FROM `post_master_user_map` WHERE posted_by_user_id=110); is also fails

Comment: "This error occurs when you try to modify a table and select from the same table in sub query." In this case you are modifying 'post_master_ser_map'  and you are selecting from same 'post_master_ser_map' in subquery

Comment: Waht i need is select the id's first from the query : SELECT id FROM post_master_user_map WHERE posted_by_user_id=110   And then delete with the query : DELETE FROM post_master_user_map WHERE reshare_id in (id's of the above result);

Comment: DELETE t1 FROM 
post_master_user_map as t1
INNER JOIN post_master_user_map as t2 ON
 t1.reshare_id=t2.id and t2.posted_by_user_id=110

Comment: Do that two same , will it can apply the updated question above ? OKay update the answer , i will accept it .

Answer (score 0):

By this [MySQL DELETE FROM with subquery as condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition) : MySQL does not allow the table you're deleting from be used in a subquery for the condition.