# Active Record Insert Into

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, subquery, insert-into

I am trying to allow my Rails App some advanced functionality in way of creating relationships. I am running MySQL as the back-end. The query below runs just fine in PHPMyAdmin, but upon attempted execution in rails, it does nothing, no errors and no database writes....

I use active record to create the relationships between Campaign and Location, and then the query below should work to build afterward in campaign_metros table:

```
class CampaignLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
    belongs_to :location

    after_touch :create_campaign_metro


    private
        def create_campaign_metro
            @sql_insert="INSERT INTO `campaign_metros` (`campaign_id`,`metro_id`, `created_at`,`updated_at`)
                    SELECT f.`campaign_id`, f.`city_id`, NOW(), NOW()
                    FROM (SELECT d.`campaign_id`, d.`city_id`
                        FROM (SELECT c.`campaign_id`, c.`city_id` 
                              FROM  (SELECT distinct a.`campaign_id`, b.`city_id`
                                        FROM `campaign_locations` a
                                        INNER JOIN `locations` b 
                                        ON a.`location_id` = b.`id`) c) d
                        LEFT JOIN `campaign_metros` e
                            ON e.`campaign_id` = d.`campaign_id` and
                               e.`metro_id`    = d.`city_id`
                        WHERE e.`metro_id` is null and e.`campaign_id` is null) f;"

            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(@sql_insert)
        end
end
```

I know from [MySQL DELETE FROM with subquery as condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition), in answer number two by CodeReaper, that MySQL requires another level of aliases when dealing with subqueries, but running my query in Rails does nothing at all.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: It turns out that all I had to do was not save as a variable, ie `@sql_insert`, but simply `sql_insert`, it all works fine now