# MySQL INSERT ... SELECT ... never ends, CPU at max

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate-functions, sql-insert

I need to delete duplicates from a table while keeping one item. Since I cannot delete from a table while accessing this very same table in a subquery inside the where-statement, i decided to store my affected IDs in a temporary table:

```
create temporary my_temp_table (
  id int not null
) engine memory;
```

and then insert IDs using a select:

```
insert into my_temp_table
  -- select query works
  select
    id
  from
    -- innodb
    table_with_duplicates
  where
    hash_code in (
    select
      hash_code
    from
      table_with_duplicates
    group by
      hash_code
    having
      count(id) > 1
    )
    and date_created < '2015-01-01'
;
```

Later I want to use these IDs to delete them:

```
delete from table_with_duplicates
  where id in (
    select id from my_temp_table
  )
;
```

Just executing the select part of the insert statement works fine. Adding the insert part, however, causes 1 CPU core to go up to 100% and the query seems to never end. Nothing is inserted.
On my dev environment, **table_with_duplicates** contains about 20000 rows with 1 duplicate.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Thank you for your answers. I have tried a **select distinct(...** approach, which didn't help much. Maybe I've used in the wrong place/subselect. Played around with it quite a lot already. To clarify, I have something like this:

```
ID    date_created    hash_code
1     2013-06-06      ABCDEFGH     <-- delete this one
2     2013-08-08      HGFEDCBA
3     2015-11-11      ABCDEFGH     <-- keep this one
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer by @ajreal for your delete with subquery problem, and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition

Comment: Why did not you use select distinct and assigned them to your temporary table?

Comment: @ajreal solved a similar problem (subselect in insert), but, the way I understand it, a different use case. btw, it was this posting where I learned, that you can't access the same table in an insert/where/select combination.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25492238/394487

Comment: well, @siride, you made my day :-) this is a rather easy way to remove duplicate items, which could have saved me a lot of time. Thanks for that. This is a potential answer post. Still am puzzled of the effect on system load my first approach had.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I chose different approach to solve this problem. I've written a small PHP command-line script that fetches all my IDs into an array and then executes a DELETE, using all IDs as ....

```
"delete from table_with_duplicates where id in (".explode(',' $arrIDs).")";
```

Having about 9000 affected rows and this (hopefully) being a one-time action, this worked for me.

I also played around with

```
SET SESSION optimizer_search_depth = 1;
```

but had no luck either.