# Delete Customer data in SQL that have not ordered since certain date

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables. A `customers` table and a `orders` table.
The `customers` table has a list of anyone that has ever placed an order, while the `orders` table has a list of every order ever made. These tables are connected on customer.ID = orders.CustomerID. Each customer has a unique ID.

The `orders` table also gives the `Date` of the order. I would like to delete all customer rows that have not ordered given a certain date.

The query I have so far is as follows:

`DELETE * FROM customers join orders on customers.id = orders.CustomerID WHERE orders.Date <= 'Date Input form Form';`

However, I fear that customers who have ordered both before and after the specified date will be removed as well, and I don't want that to happen.

The logic I'm looking for is more so like this:

```
delete customers where the orders.date is !> than the given date
```

Even then, will this logic protect customers who have ordered before the given date and after the given date?

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: this will delete any customer that has ordered before the given date.

Comment: Yes, but if they have ONLY ordered before the given date, those are the ones I want to delete. @JonathanVanDam

Comment: Use a sub query to find the max(orders.Date) for each customer and only remove the ones that are less than the date specified. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you perhaps propose a query similar to this?

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer.id NOT IN
(SELECT order.customer_id from orders where order.date > cutoff)
```

Where customers must have ordered something after cutoff to be kept.