# What should LIMIT have for attributes in Spring JPA? SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to have limits with `nativeQuery = true` but Spring JPA can't find the query for this.

My error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract void se.danielmartensson.repositories.DataRepository.deleteByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit(java.lang.String,long,long) but parameter 'Optional[jobName]' not found in annotated query 'DELETE FROM Data data ORDER BY data.dateTime WHERE data.jobName =: jobName LIMIT firstIndex = :firstIndex, selectedSamples = :selectedSamples'!
```

So I'm guessing that `LIMIT` should have different attributes, rather than `firstIndex` and `selectedSamples` ? What can it be then?

Where is my query from my `Repository` in Spring Boot

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Data data ORDER BY data.dateTime WHERE data.jobName = :jobName LIMIT firstIndex = :firstIndex, selectedSamples = :selectedSamples", nativeQuery = true)
List<Data> findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("firstIndex") long firstIndex, @Param("selectedSamples") long selectedSamples);

@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Data data ORDER BY data.dateTime WHERE data.jobName =: jobName LIMIT firstIndex = :firstIndex, selectedSamples = :selectedSamples", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("firstIndex") long firstIndex, @Param("selectedSamples") long selectedSamples);
```

Comment: I think you got a typo here `=: jobName LIMIT`

Comment: @T.Peter Thank you. Now I got `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE data.jobName = 'Test3' LIMIT firstIndex = 0, selectedSamples = 104' at line 1` I have tried with `AND` between `Test3`  and `LIMIT` without success.

Comment: I'll kindly ask you to re-edit your post which contains the problem in comment, so new comer can spot the actual problem.

Comment: Also `limit` is a clause that is used to set an upper limit on the number of tuples returned by SQL. I don't think `limit` is what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample project that uses `H2`. You must change `limit` and `offset` part in which database you are using. For the delete operation, there is `delete from table where id in (select id from table where .. order by .. limit .. offset ..)` is defined.

Note: `Lombok` is used for `getter`, `setter` and `toString`. It is not required.

**DataRepository.java**

```java
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Data data WHERE data.jobName = :jobName ORDER BY data.dateTime limit :selectedSamples offset :firstIndex"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    List<Data>findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("firstIndex") Integer firstIndex, @Param("selectedSamples") Integer selectedSamples);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM Data data WHERE data.id in (select id from Data d where d.jobName = :jobName order by d.dateTime limit :selectedSamples offset :firstIndex)"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteByJobNameOrderByDateTime(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("firstIndex") Integer firstIndex, @Param("selectedSamples") Integer selectedSamples);
}
```

**Data.java**

```java
@lombok.Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Data {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "jobName")
    private String jobName;

    @Column(name = "dateTime")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public Data() {
    }

    public Data(String jobName, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

### Test

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;
    
    @Test
    void test1() {
        // insert dummy records
        dataRepository.save(new Data("job1", LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(1)));
        dataRepository.save(new Data("job1", LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(2)));
        dataRepository.save(new Data("job1", LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(3)));
        dataRepository.save(new Data("job1", LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(4)));

        // get records
        List<Data> dataList = dataRepository.findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit("job1", 0, 4);
        for (Data data : dataList) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }

        // delete
        dataRepository.deleteByJobNameOrderByDateTime("job1", 1, 2);

        // get records
        dataList = dataRepository.findByJobNameOrderByDateTimeLimit("job1", 0, 4);
        for (Data data : dataList) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM Data data WHERE data.jobName = ? ORDER BY data.dateTime limit ? offset ?

Data(id=4, jobName=job1, dateTime=2021-01-08T05:25:31.830)
Data(id=3, jobName=job1, dateTime=2021-01-08T05:26:31.829)
Data(id=2, jobName=job1, dateTime=2021-01-08T05:27:31.827)
Data(id=1, jobName=job1, dateTime=2021-01-08T05:28:31.756)

Hibernate: DELETE FROM Data data WHERE data.id in (select id from Data d where d.jobName = ? order by d.dateTime limit ? offset ?)

Hibernate: SELECT * FROM Data data WHERE data.jobName = ? ORDER BY data.dateTime limit ? offset ?

Data(id=4, jobName=job1, dateTime=2021-01-08T05:25:31.830)
Data(id=1, jobName=job1, dateTime=2021-01-08T05:28:31.756)
```

### Mysql

For `mysql` delete operation is successful with below script.

Reference: [MySQL DELETE FROM with subquery as condition - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969601/13106495)

```java
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM Data WHERE id in (select id from (select id from Data where jobName = :jobName order by dateTime limit :selectedSamples offset :firstIndex) x)"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteByJobNameOrderByDateTime(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("firstIndex") Integer firstIndex, @Param("selectedSamples") Integer selectedSamples);
```

Comment: Very good! This is a good answer. Unforteny it won't work on my MySQL database. I don't know why I'm using MySQL. It just works. MySQL don't have the keyword `ÌN`.

Comment: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
`

Comment: Hi @DanielMårtensson I have found an answer from [MySQL DELETE FROM with subquery as condition - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969601/13106495). It is working now for mysql

Comment: Hi!  This works for me `DELETE FROM data WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM data WHERE job_name = :jobName ORDER BY date_time ASC LIMIT :selectedLimit OFFSET :selectedOffset) as t)` MySQL.

Comment: Yes. It's  similar code as you show. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the row which `jobName` and `firstIndex` and `selectedSamples` match the parameters. you should use correct SQL syntax and put them in `where`.

```
SELECT * FROM Data data
WHERE data.jobName = :jobName AND firstIndex = :firstIndex AND selectedSamples = :selectedSamples
ORDER BY data.dateTime
```

the correct syntax is like this :

```
select *
from [table]
where 'condiction'
order by [column]
limit [int]
```

---

`LIMIT` however is used to set the max tuples SQL return, for example if the query return 10K rows but you only want to look at first 5 rows, you can use `limit 5` to tell SQL only return first 5 fetch.

Also in different DBMS there might need to use different syntax or method to achieve the same thing, like in ORACLE we got no `limit` clause, instead we got `FETCH` or simply using `ROWNUM`.