# if I want to delete some data in mysql, can I use delete from table where xxx='xxx' and indexID not in (select * table a where xxx='xxx limit 3)?

Tags: mysql

if I want to delete some data in mysql, can I use

`delete from table where xxx='xxx' and indexID not in (select * table where xxx='xxx limit 3)`??

because when I used this code, I got the error.

I know how to working in mssql,

`DELETE  FROM  table  WHERE  xxx  =  'xxx'  AND  indexID  NOT  IN (SELECT  TOP(3)  indexID  FROM  table  WHERE  xxx  =  'xxx'  ORDER  BY  check_date  DESC`

Comment: In your nested query it shouldn't be select * but it should be selecting the id column only

Comment: `I got the error` ... what was the error?  Also note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` generally makes no sense.  You should explain the logic of your query, maybe by adding sample data.

Comment: @WadihM. I'd tried used SELECT indexID FROM sis_User_password_check WHERE userid ='admin' order by chk_date, but will got This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because I have to delete the last three data

Comment: After googling your error message, I find this post, which might have your solution. Essentially it is using a join instead of a IN subquery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu. Make sure to do some testing to get the algorithm right

Comment: @dMd So I cannot do it in mysql? but can do it in mssql?

Comment: You can use joins or double subquery if you deleting and selecting from same table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition