# How to delete similar rows from my table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, delete-row

I'd like to perform a cleanup in one of my MySQL Drupal tables to remove duplicate values stored. Here is the structure:

```
NID  VID   DELTA   FIELD_VALUE
100  100   0       foobar
100  100   1       foobar
101  101   0       barbar
101  101   1       barbar
102  102   0       foofoo
```

My goal is to remove rows with bigger `DELTA`s if a row with the same `NID, VID, FIELD_VALUE` exists with smaller `DELTA`.

My first attempt was the following query:

`delete from mytable a where a.delta=1 and 1=(select count(nid) from mytable b where b.nid=a.nid and b.vid=a.vid and b.delta=0 and b.field_value=a.field_value)`

Unfortunately the DB says: (MySQL 5.1.65-cll)

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a where a.delta=1 and 1 = (select count from `field_value` b where' at line 1
```

which is not very helpful to me.

UPDATE:

A deleted answer told me that MySQL does not support alias in delete statements, but removing aliases did not help. The subquery is ok, checked separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
DELETE a
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b ON (a.nid = b.nid
                AND a.vid = b.vid
                AND a.field_value = b.field_value)
WHERE a.delta > b.delta
```

(don't forget to backup your data)

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself on three columns (`NID, VID, FIELD_VALUE`) and SELECT the MAX value for `DELTA`.

This will work as long as you don't have any other columns involved.

[Here is a good example for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192849/1709629)

Comment: Ok, `SELECT max( a.delta )
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b ON ( a.nid = b.nid
AND a.vid = b.vid
AND a.field_value = b.field_value )` yields 7. But how to use this in the delete?