# MySQL joins for delete

Tags: php, mysql, join, phpmyadmin, left-join

I have multiple tables 
list_of_students, sport_students.

in sport_students I have field named

list_of_house_id and in list_of_students I have field list_of_class_id, and list_of_house_id.

Now but I need to delete records from sport_student acc to house_id and list_of_class_id.

I have tried this query but seems not working

```
DELETE FROM `sport_students` JOIN list_of_students as student on `sport_student.list_house_id`= `student.list_of_house_id` WHERE `sport_student.list_of_house_id`=1 and `list_of_students.list_of_class_id`=1
```

Anybody have idea how to do this?

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/mysql-delete-w-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE  FROM sport_students
WHERE   list_of_house_id IN (
            SELECT  list_of_house_id
            FROM    list_of_students
            WHERE   list_of_class_id = 1 AND list_of_house_id =1 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE sp
  FROM `sport_students` sp
  JOIN list_of_students as student 
    ON sp.list_house_id = student.list_of_house_id
 WHERE sp.list_of_house_id=1 
   AND student.list_of_class_id=1;
```

For more see [MySQL: Delete Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)