# PHP MySQL prepared statement in a prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

In `modelSlikeVrijednost` I have a reference to the `model`-s primary key. `ModelSlikeVrijednost` can contain a lot of images (depends on the user). I need to delete the folder based on the `modelID`.

Example of path: `/home/mainSite/public_html/site/img/1/1/`.

Is it possible to do this ?

Code:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT modelID FROM model WHERE proizvodacID='$id'")) {    
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($modelID);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $path="/home/mainSite/public_html/site/img/".$id."/".$modelID."/";

        if ($stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT modelSlikeVrijednost FROM modelSlike WHERE modelID='$modelID'")) {    
            $stmt1->execute();

            $stmt1->bind_result($slike);

            while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
                if(is_null($slike)){
                    rmdir($path);
                }
                else{
                    $slikePath="/home/mainSite/public_html/site/".$slike;
                    if($slikePath!=$path){
                        unlink($slikePath);
                    }
                   rmdir($path);
                }
             }

            $stmt1->close();

        }
        else {
            printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();

}
```

I get this **error** :`Prepared Statement Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now Prepared Statement Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: You should bind your variables in the prepared statements.

Comment: sql results usually come back as array objects, not strings. try echoing $modelID and see what shows up before trying to use it in another statement.

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: Not when one is using `mysqli::bind_result` which binds a column value directly to a PHP variable.

Comment: @prodigitalson so if you had a query that returned multiple rows, would it throw an error?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: No, it binds the variable to the column value from the current row everytime `mysqil_stmt::fetch` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant.... you need to loop through all the results, close the cursor, or use a separate connection.

However what you are trying to do is better accomplished with a join anyway...

```
SELECT ms.modelSlikeVrijednost, m.modelID FROM model m, modelSlike ms
WHERE ms.modelID= m.modelID
AND m.proizvodacID ='$id'
```

This will give you all the information you need in each row.

However you ar also using prepared statements incorrectly. You shouldnt be passing in php variables directly you should be binding them as parameters to the query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ms.modelSlikeVrijednost, m.modelID FROM model m, modelSlike ms'
       .' WHERE ms.modelID= m.modelID'
       .' AND m.proizvodacID = ?';

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

   // bind the $id to the parameter as an integer
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

   $stmt->execute();

   // bind the fields of the result to the same variables you had before
   $stmt->bind_result($slike, $modelID);

   // less prone to error if we only type this manually once :-)
   $basePath = "/home/mainSite/public_html/site";

   while($stmt->fetch()) {

        $path= $basePath . "/img/".$id."/".$modelID."/";
        $slikePath = $basePath . "/" . $slike;

        if(is_null($slike)){
          rmdir($path);
        } else {
           if($slikePath!=$path) {
              unlink($slikePath);
           }

           rmdir($path);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Just one more question, how can I achieve the same thing but only with delete ? Same first query but instead of the second , I use `DELETE FROM modelLinkovi WHERE modelID='$modelID'`. It only deletes the last record.

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you are asking but i think you want to `DELETE` form both `model` and `modelLinkovi`... If thats that case your query would look like: `DELETE FROM model m, modelLinkovi ml WHERE ml.modelID = m.modelID AND m.modelID = ?`

Comment: Of course since they both have the `modelID` column the `ml.modelID = m.modelID` is a bit redundant but its more consistent with what you use to pull data.

Comment: I want to `DELETE` from `modelSlike` based on the `modelID ` in `model`. Example, the `modelID` in `model` is `1` and in `modelSlike` I have 3 rows that reference to that `1`. The query for that would be `DELETE FROM modelSlike WHERE modelID='1'`. Now I want to use the same query but to loop through the `modelID`. Is that possible ?

Comment: Can you create another question with the schema for `modelSlike` and `model` along with an explanation of the relationship and what you want deleted?

Comment: I found the answere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/mysql-delete-w-join). Anyway, thanks for the answer for the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use bare mysqli API.
Get yourself a helper class, like [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)
Then your code would be

```
$models = $db->getCol("SELECT modelID FROM model WHERE proizvodacID=?i",$id);
foreach($models as $modelID) {
    $path  = "/home/mainSite/public_html/site/img/$id/$modelID/";
    $sql   = "SELECT modelSlikeVrijednost FROM modelSlike WHERE modelID=?i";
    $sarr  = $db->getCol($sql, $modelID));

    foreach($sarr as $silke) {
        if(!$slike)) {
           rmdir($path);
        } else {
            $slikePath="/home/mainSite/public_html/site/".$slike;
            if($slikePath!=$path){
                unlink($slikePath);
            }
                rmdir($path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But yes, it's better to do it in one query, like prodigitalson said:

```
$sql = "SELECT ms.modelSlikeVrijednost, m.modelID FROM model m, modelSlike ms
        WHERE ms.modelID= m.modelID AND m.proizvodacID=?i";
$sarr = $db->getCol($sql, $id);
foreach($sarr as $silke) {
    if(!$slike)) {
       rmdir($path);
    } else {
        $slikePath="/home/mainSite/public_html/site/".$slike;
        if($slikePath!=$path){
            unlink($slikePath);
        }
            rmdir($path);
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to get your data already from the query and then use it.

Comment: +1 for recommending a helper class. The Mysqli API cant be laborious to use (which is one of the reasons i prefer PDO) so a helper that abstracts some of the craziness away is good.

Comment: Good to know that there is a helper class for this issue. Will definitely use it next time.