# sql Inner join delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have tow tables

> tests_sub ,tests_sub_sub

and `tests_sub.id  =  tests_sub_sub.id`

so i want to delete data from both tables with one

> sql query

I used the following inner join

```
DELETE tests_sub, tests_sub_sub FROM tests_sub
INNER JOIN tests_sub_sub ON tests_sub_sub.id = tests_sub.id
WHERE tests_sub.id = 10
```

the query works ok only if both tables have entries for the tests_sub.id...
 ( if tests_sub_sub has no entry for test_sub.id = 10 ... although the table tests_sub has entries for that id no rows are affected ...
please suggest some tips....

Comment: Please refer to this link to delete using join
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql

Comment: use Left join I think that resolve your problem

Comment: Inner join produces only the set of records that match in both Table A and Table B. Try using `Left Outer Join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
DELETE tests_sub, tests_sub_sub 
FROM   tests_sub
       LEFT JOIN tests_sub_sub 
          ON tests_sub_sub.id = tests_sub.id
WHERE  tests_sub.id = 10
```

Comment: thanks bro....but how to if there are 3 tables ???......................DELETE tests,tests_sub FROM tests
LEFT JOIN tests_sub ON tests_sub.idtests = tests.idtests
LEFT JOIN tests_sub_sub ON tests_sub_sub.idtests_sub = tests_sub.idtests_sub
WHERE tests.idtests = 10

Comment: the same, add `DELETE a, b, c
FROM   a
       LEFT JOIN b
          ON .... LEFT JOIN c on ....
WHERE  ....` -- if you want to delete in 3 tables.