# Difference between single-table and multiple-table syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm trying to understand how MYSQL determines single-table and multiple table syntax but I can't find this information. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) explains how MYSQL handles the two, but it doesn't explain what determines them.

Documentation says:

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows
>   from one or more tables depending on the particular condition in the
>   WHERE clause. However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a
>   multiple-table DELETE.

Take this query for example:

```
DELETE table FROM table
INNER JOIN other ON other.column = table.column
WHERE other.column2 = ?
LIMIT 1
```

Is this single or multiple table syntax? There's a `JOIN`, so you could lean toward multiple, but it's only deleting from one table. My other suspicion is that it's determined when multiple `WHERE` clauses are used for multiple tables. If you could include examples of both in your answer it would be much appreciated!

**EDIT :**
I'm asking this question because when performing certain `DELETE` queries with a `LIMIT` I get an error that you cannot use `LIMIT` with multiple-table syntax.

**EDIT #2:**
In a nutshell, you cannot use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` if you are joining tables in a `DELETE` query.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't worry about the terminology.  WYou understand the concept here - MySQL can delete from several tables if they're specified after the `DELETE` keyword in a `JOIN`'ed delete statement

Comment: Other than that specific page in MySQL's docs, I don't think I've ever read or heard those terms used, but given that you _have to specify `table`_ in the `DELETE` clause, I guess I'd call this "multiple table syntax".  If it was truly single-table, it would not be necessary to name `table` after the `DELETE` keyword

Comment: Similar answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql

Comment: I'm wondering, because as it states in the documentation you can only use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with single-table syntax. It's not just a curiosity.

Comment: Add that to your question then, because that is pertinent information.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried to do a `DELETE` from only _one_ of the two joined tables like your example, with an `ORDER BY/LIMIT` clause and MySQL reported a syntax error. So given that, it's "multi-table".

Comment: ^^^ I'll put this as an answer,  I guess, because it seems to be unambiguous after testing.

Comment: Understood @MichaelBerkowski, but I would really like to know the criteria.

Comment: @EternalHour The criteria appears to be whether a JOIN is present at all. The presence of any `JOIN` results in a syntax error if either 1) a table is _not_ specified in the `DELETE` clause or 2) an `ORDER BY` is supplied. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if you believe it's based strictly on `JOIN` it's sufficient.

Comment: @EternalHour Okay, I did a whole bunch of tests and it looks like the first `t` in `DELETE t FROM t...` is really the thing that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL's documentation states the following](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Regarding the "single-table" synatax:

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are deleted in the order that is specified. The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be deleted.

Regarding the "multi-table" syntax:

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

---

Some testing is revealing in the matter of the `ORDER BY` limitations.

This is a valid single-table `DELETE` statement with an `ORDER BY`:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE somecol = 'someval'
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2
```

A similar query with an explicit joining condition against one other table results in a syntax error on the `ORDER BY`, despite only one of the tables being targeted for deletion:

```
DELETE table1 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE somecol = 'someval'
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2' at line 1

Specifying the same query with an implicit join fails the same way

```
DELETE table1 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE
  table1.id = table2.id
  AND somecol = 'someval'
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2' at line 1

Specifying no table after `DELETE` for deletion in a joined (multi-table) statement so it looks more like a single-table syntax is also a syntax error

```
DELETE /* no table named here */
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE somecol = 'someval'
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE somecol

#### It's the table named in the `DELETE` clause:

Finally, using *only one* table, but with the mult-table syntax (naming a table after the `DELETE` keyword) does *not* permit an `ORDER BY`, so  **the true identifying difference here appears to be tables named in the `DELETE` clause** to distinguish multi-table from single-table:

This query only involves one table (without a join), but produces a syntax error:

```
/* name table1 in the DELETE clause */
DELETE table1
/* but not other table is joined */
FROM table1
WHERE somecol = 'someval'
ORDER BY id LIMIT 2
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id LIMIT 1

Comment: @EternalHour Happy to help. I learned a lot of new things researching this.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify that you `DELETE` from only 1 table and there are no `JOIN`s involved in your `DELETE` statement, then it's a single-table syntax. Otherwise, it's a multi-table syntax. I am pretty sure that's what the doc page means.

I think a proof for this interpretation is that down there the page says:

> The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described in Section 13.2.8.2, "JOIN Syntax".

Note that in the single-table syntax there's no `table_references` element.