# SQL Delete with relation to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I have two tables, for example:

TableA with columns GUID,ProgKey,UserKey,ProgName.

TableB with columns GUID,AppKey,ModeName. Foreign Key: GUID->TableA.GUID

*I need to delete TableB.AppKey with specific value but only with the condition where TableA.UserKey= specific value.*

I tried something simple like this but it didn't work:

```
Delete from TableB b, TableA a where b.AppKey=? and a.UserKey=?
```

And tried this, also didn't work:

```
Delete from TableB (AppKey) Select ? From TableB b, TableA a where a.UserKey=?
```

?=appkeyValue000

?=userkeyValue000

GUID is a primary key.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql for a response several years old that has several comments relating to which is best.

Comment: @PeterBowers
Thank you! That has made things clear for me. Will use join instead of "and   in (select...)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

```
DELETE tableB FROM tableB JOIN tableA ON (tableB.GUID = tableA.GUID)
WHERE tableA.UserKey = 'userkeyValue000'
AND tableB.AppKey = 'appkeyValue000'
```

The deletion occurs in the table(s) occurring before the FROM keyword.

Comment: Thank you! It works! However, I am not sure which answer to use: this one (seems to be lighter) or Table-JOIN... Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

delete from table where id in (select id from table2 where y=234)?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete using a JOIN, which seems like the most natural way IMO.

```
DELETE TableB
FROM TableB JOIN TableA ON TableA.GUID = TableB.GUID
WHERE TableB.AppKey = <Value> AND TableA.UserKey = <OtherVal>;
```