# sql syntax error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, join

I have this query:

```
"UPDATE Bookings SET total=0 
FROM Bookings JOIN Vehicles on Bookings.CustomerID=Vehicles.CustomerID
WHERE hasWarranty='yes'";
```

Every time I run it, it says `Syntax error near 'from'` and I don't know why.

I basically want to check: does the vehicle associated with the booking have warranty - if it does, set `total` to 0. I want to update the value of one table if another value in another table equals x.

Comment: An update statement has no from clause.

Comment: Because the syntax is wrong. You need to look at the update query syntax.

Comment: @avk Microsoft SQL Server `UPDATE` does a have from clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx but given the error the OP is probably using MySQL.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel. Did not know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no FROM in UPDATE clauses.
You have to completely rewrite this query.

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Bookings SET total=0 
WHERE (SELECT hasWarranty FROM Vehicles WHERE Vehicles.CustomerID = Bookings.CustomerID) = 'yes'
```

Comment: just tried this and no syntax error anymore but if warranty is equal to no its still updates it to 0

Comment: You're welcome! Just to make sure you don't run into issues: You might want to think about the question if it still works in case your application supports several Vehicles for one CustomerID because in this case a random Vehicle is chosen for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the FROM keyword when doing an update

```
UPDATE Bookings AS b JOIN Vehicles AS v ON b.CustomerId = v.CustomerID SET b.total = 0 WHERE v.hasWarranty = 'yes';
```

Comment: You missed the `JOIN`.

Comment: I have never done a join in an update, actually thought it would lead to invalid syntax as well.  I would have to play with this to put the join in place but I also see no reason for a join since hasWarranty seems to be in the Booking table.

Comment: The following query will work as well but there is no need to join tables unless you are using a value from the joined table, in this case it does not appear to be using a reference from the Vehicles table.  If hasWarranty is in the Vehicles table then you would reference it by v.hasWarranty rather than b.hasWarranty.


UPDATE Bookings AS b JOIN Vehicles AS v ON b.CustomerId = v.CustomerID SET b.total = 0 WHERE b.hasWarranty = 'yes';

Comment: It would seem to me that `hasWarranty` would make much more sense to be on a vehicle, not a booking. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4192849/811240) about joins on delete. Updates should work the same way.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)  Thanks for pointing that out Mike.  I've just never had a reason to cross join tables on an update :)

Comment: ok thought it was working but it sets total to 0 for all warranties not just where warranty is equal to yes.  hasWarranty is in a Vehicles table not Bookings;)

Comment: Hmm I just realized that this question is sqlite. For some reason I had MySQL in my mind, so you would have to test it to see if it works in sqlite as well.

Comment: doesn't work in sqllite as updates all to 0, when i use josephs update it again gives me a syntax error.

Comment: it doesn't update the first row where hasWarranty is equal to no but updates the rest of the rows

Comment: @u.1234 What table are `hasWarranty` and `CustomerID` on?

Comment: hasWarranty is in Vehicles and CustomerID is in Bookings

Comment: it doesn't even look at the has warranty part just updates all values

Comment: @u.1234 If you look at this query, you will notice that "`Vehicles`" does not even appear anywhere. If you want the update to be dependent of a value in the `Vehicles` table, you have to do a `JOIN`. It's not going to be able to get the value if you don't.

Comment: i was talking about the solution you submitted it updates them all doesn't even look at hasWarranty

Comment: oh sorry not you who submitted someone else!