# MYSQL Syntax incorrect

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following statement below that is getting an error of `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c
    JOIN campaignsFroms f      ON f.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsRaw r        ON r.' at line 2`

What syntax am I missing?

**Code:**

```
DELETE 
    FROM campaigns c
    JOIN campaignsFroms f      ON f.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsRaw r        ON r.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsSubjects s   ON s.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignIPTracking ip ON ip.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignTracking ct   ON ct.id = c.id
    WHERE c.id = '1582'
```

Comment: Have you tried just retyping `c
    JOIN campaignsFroms f      ON f.id = c.id
    JOIN campaignsRaw r        ON r.` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql

Comment: Excerpt from the other question: a) You cannot use an alias for the main table (so the alias `c` has to be removed). b) You must specify which table you are deleting from in a multi-table delete, so the statement should start with `DELETE campaigns FROM campaigns`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 DELETE c
FROM campaigns c
JOIN campaignsFroms f      ON f.id = c.id
JOIN campaignsRaw r        ON r.id = c.id
JOIN campaignsSubjects s   ON s.id = c.id
JOIN campaignIPTracking ip ON ip.id = c.id
JOIN campaignTracking ct   ON ct.id = c.id
WHERE c.id = '1582'
```

Comment: can you delete using joins??

Comment: Why downvote ? The syntax is correct for delete with JOIN.