# MySQL - select and then delete, preferably in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

We often need to do following, retrieve product ids for a user and then delete them from the database.

```
select id from mytable where user=123;
```

and then we delete those id returned from query above:

```
delete from mytable where id in (1, 5, 6, 7);
```

It is possible that while select is returning data from server to client, a new record for that user is inserted and hence we are selectively deleting ids.

Is there a better way to achieve it?

Thanks

**Edit**: some of you have answered, 
   delete from mytable where user=123;

but it's a wrong answer as a new row might be inserted between mysql server completed the query and mysql client yet to receive response from the server.

Comment: What if the application cannot complete its processing?  Your method seems reasonable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql

Comment: what don't just do `delete from mytable where user=123`?

Comment: If both query is related to the same table, why can't you use "delete from mytable where user=123;"?

Comment: What means `new record for that user is inserted`?

Comment: When you want to delete SOME rows from user 123, but not "new" ones, you have a state that depends on a race condition rather than data. Are the "ids" nullable? Do you only want specific rows from user XY / 123 to be deleted?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp on the record? if so that could be used to control which ones you delete.This is probably the easiest.  Another approach is to have a 'state' column on the record. Always set to new on insert then updated later. Including specifically marking it for deletion?

Comment: @mb14 It's a wrong answer - pls read my updates.

Comment: @RyanVincent and how do you make the state white select. It's a same problem again. timestamp likely to work 99% but no guarantee that two items won't be having the same time stamp.

Comment: i think you need to better explain your problem with more details