# MySql Delete not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql delete script which gives me an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN mall ON mall.m_id = unifo.mids WHERE mallnames = 'My Mall'' at line 2

Delete query:

```
DELETE FROM unifo 
LEFT JOIN mall ON mall.m_id = unifo.mids 
WHERE mallnames = 'My Mall' && time_insert < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 25 
MINUTE
```

I cannot find my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a basic issue in this query

```
DELETE FROM unifo 
LEFT JOIN mall ON mall.m_id = unifo.mids 
WHERE mallnames = 'My Mall' && time_insert < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 25 
MINUTE
```

your performing a left join with mall table and then base on mall value your going to delete something but in left join mallname can be null no point of left joining it

2 specify the table

DELETE unifo FROM unifo ....

Answer (score 1):

You may need to say which table you are deleting from, as in this answer: [Delete with Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You have two tables in the `from`, but do not specify which to delete from.

I would recommend uses table aliases as well:

```
DELETE u
    FROM unifo u LEFT JOIN
         mall m
         ON m.m_id = u.mids 
WHERE mallnames = 'My Mall' AND time_insert < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 25 MINUTE ;
```

This assumes that you want to delete the rows from `unifo`.