# MySQL delete multiple rows in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to **delete** multiple records from three tables at once in one query?

> **categories:**
>   *id, name*
> **sub_categories:**
>    *id, category_id,
>   name*
>  **items:**
>   *id, subcategory_id, name*

I have `id` of the category that I need to delete. For example, `5`

The SQL query must delete the category with that `id`.

```
categories.id = 5
```

Also, it must delete all the subcategories from that category.

```
sub_categories.category_id = categories.id
```

And finally, delete all items from those subcategories that where removed in step 2.

```
items.subcategory_id = sub_categories.id
```

Comment: FOREIGN KEY ..  ON DELETE CASCADE option will force delete childs when parent is deleted

Comment: A Transaction would seem like a good idea if you dont want to CASCADE DELETE [Start here in the manual for MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) or [Start here for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can delete from multiple tables if you introduce foreign key constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

This is the other way around:

```
DELETE C,SC,I
FROM categories C 
INNER JOIN sub_categories SC ON C.id = SC.category_id
INNER JOIN items I ON SC.id = I.subcategory_id
WHERE C.id = 5;
```

Check this <kbd>[**Delete with join(multiple tables)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql/38939059#38939059)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

If sub categories don't have any item under it then you need to replace the last `INNER JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN`

```
DELETE C,SC,I
FROM categories C 
INNER JOIN sub_categories SC ON C.id = SC.category_id
LEFT JOIN items I ON SC.id = I.subcategory_id
WHERE C.id = 5;
```

Comment: I guess this code will not remove empty sub_categories?

Comment: Empty sub categories means?

Comment: I mean sub_categories that does not contain any items.

Comment: In fact this code will remove a particular category, all sub categories under this category and all items under those sub categories

Comment: Yes you are right. In that case replace the last inner join by left join

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

try **[ON Delete Cascade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)**

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE sub_categories(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  category_id int(11) NOT NULL,      
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) 
  REFERENCES categories (category_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```