# Sql delete using inner join more than 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I run this sql statement to delete from database using inner join, but i get too many errors

**Error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN
>   ipaddress_likes_map ON ipaddress_likes_map.postat = blog_post.BID INN'
>   at line 3' in C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net_inc\dbcontroller.php:57
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net_inc\dbcontroller.php(57):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net\user\deleteaccount.php(88):
>   DBController->execute() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net_inc\dbcontroller.php on line 57

**here is my code**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
     $pass = $_POST['pasyske'];
     $userkey = $_POST['username'];
     $db_delete = new DBController();
     $db_delete->prepare("DELETE
FROM blog_post
INNER JOIN ipaddress_likes_map ON ipaddress_likes_map.postat = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN flagpost ON flagpost.postId = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN postviewmap ON postviewmap.viewpostId = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN replys ON replys.rid = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN votepoint_map ON votepoint_map.postlike_id = blog_post.BID
WHERE blog_post.UserName = :alluserpost");
     $db_delete->bind(":alluserpost", $userkey);
     //$db_delete->bind(":password", $encrypt_password);
     $db_delete->execute();
     $pdeleted = $db_delete->getAll(); 
     $db_delete->free();

    if($pdeleted){
        print_r($pdeleted);
    }

   }?>
```

I'm sure my db controller is okay because when i run single delete statement it work very fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete with Join in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each table an alias and reference it right after the word `DELETE`. Also, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` because I'm guessing you still want the deletes to work event if some of the joined tables don't have matching rows.

```
db_delete->prepare("DELETE bp, i, f, p, r, v
FROM blog_post AS bp
LEFT JOIN ipaddress_likes_map AS i ON i.postat = bp.BID
LEFT JOIN flagpost AS f ON f.postId = bp.BID
LEFT JOIN postviewmap AS p ON p.viewpostId = bp.BID
LEFT JOIN replys AS r ON r.rid = bp.BID
LEFT JOIN votepoint_map AS v ON v.postlike_id = bp.BID
WHERE bp.UserName = :alluserpost");
```

Comment: i got this error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pb.BID' in 'on clause'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net\_inc\dbcontroller.php:57 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net\_inc\dbcontroller.php(57): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net\user\deleteaccount.php(88): DBController->execute() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\codejail.net\_inc\dbcontroller.php on line 57`

Comment: Whoops! Typo. `pb` => `bp`. Just fixed it. Try again, please.

Answer (score 0):

After DELETE you should tell from what table to delete rows. Try this query:

```
$db_delete->prepare("DELETE blog_post 
FROM blog_post
INNER JOIN ipaddress_likes_map ON ipaddress_likes_map.postat = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN flagpost ON flagpost.postId = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN postviewmap ON postviewmap.viewpostId = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN replys ON replys.rid = blog_post.BID
INNER JOIN votepoint_map ON votepoint_map.postlike_id = blog_post.BID
WHERE blog_post.UserName = :alluserpost");
```

Comment: No error but the table didn't delete @Andrej Ludinovskov