# Delete data from a single table from inner join result

Tags: mysql

I have this query in mysql.

```
SELECT
    a.*, b.material_tools_group
FROM
    borrowing_mat_master_data AS a
INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b ON a.tools_code = b.material_code
WHERE
    material_tools_group IN (
        'Consumable',
        'Material'
    )
ORDER BY
    `a`.`tools_code` ASC
```

I want to delete the result from the query above, I've tried this query below but it doesn't work.

```
DELETE
FROM
    borrowing_mat_master_data
WHERE
    tools_code IN (
        SELECT
            a.*, b.material_tools_group
        FROM
            borrowing_mat_master_data AS a
        INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b ON a.tools_code = b.material_code
        WHERE
            material_tools_group IN (
                'Consumable',
                'Material'
            )
    );
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Other than using `DELETE` *instead of* `SELECT`?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In order to delete data from `borrowing_mat_master_data` table out of the joined result:**

```
DELETE a
FROM
    borrowing_mat_master_data AS a
INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b ON a.tools_code = b.material_code
WHERE
    material_tools_group IN (
        'Consumable',
        'Material'
    );
```

---

**In order to delete data both from `borrowing_mat_master_data` and `material_tools_master_data` table out of the joined result:**

```
DELETE a,b
FROM
    borrowing_mat_master_data AS a
INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b ON a.tools_code = b.material_code
WHERE
    material_tools_group IN (
        'Consumable',
        'Material'
    )
```

---

See [**Delete with join (single table, multiple tables)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql/38939059#38939059)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete whole records of form table name ***borrowing_mat_master_data***  and only *material_tools_group* column from table name ***material_tools_master_data*** use following query i hope it will help you.

```
DELETE a FROM borrowing_mat_master_data AS a
INNER JOIN material_tools_master_data AS b ON a.tools_code = b.material_code
WHERE
    b.material_tools_group IN (
        'Consumable',
        'Material'
    )
```

Comment: Rana, any DELETE statement will always delete **rows** (if any are found).