# Delete from table1 and records associated in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, double

I'm trying to make a simple decision deleting records from database.
I have a main table with records and the unique ID it's auto increment.

Then I have a second table that stores values(could be more than one) associating the ID from the first table.

Example:

```
table1
editors
ID (autoincrement)
EditorName
```

Then I have a second table with:

```
table2
ID
editorID (same ID as table1)
bookname
```

So this way I want to know how could be the best way to delete a record from table1 (example ID=2) and it automatically deletes all records from table2 where editorID=2.

I've tried many ways but it seems they don't work unless I do two queries but I don't like that way. There's a smarter way to do that? It must be by code or I could associate two tables in SQL and they associated by ID and editorID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1:**

If you have foreign key constraint in `table2` which refers to the `ID` of `table1` having `ON DELETE CASCADE` behavior then deleting records from `table1` will delete the corresponding entries from `table2`.

**Solution #2:**

You can delete multiple tables using `JOIN`

```
DELETE T1,T2
FROM table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN table2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.editorID
WHERE T1.ID = 2;
```

See <kbd>[**Related post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql/38939059#38939059)</kbd>

---

**EDIT:**

In order to delete entries from `table1` and `table2` irrespective of whether corresponding entries exist in `table2` or not you need to replace the `INNER JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN`

```
  DELETE T1,T2
  FROM table1 AS T1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.editorID
  WHERE T1.ID = 2;
```

Comment: It works if table1 and 2 have values. Imagine that only table1 have values. Since I want to delete both, it doesn't delete as table2 doesn't have vlaues. Any way to do that?

Comment: just replace the `inner join` by `left join`. Please check the updated answer  under **edit** section. @Tiago

Answer (score 0):

make a foreign key for linking those 2 table

Define a foreign key between these two tables, and let MySQL know when to cascade whenever an editor is deleted:

```
CREATE TABLE editors (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EditorName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE edits (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  bookname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  editorID int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  KEY editorID (editorID),
  CONSTRAINT edits_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (editorID) 
  REFERENCES editors (ID) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Nowhere near enough information to be considered an answer

Comment: I agree it's not enough information, but he had the correct idea. I added a code sample to demonstrate this. Using triggers work too, but it's difficult to setup in comparison to just setting a foreign key.

Comment: @DaveChen how is setting up a trigger difficult and where in the question does it reference a parent child relationship that would generate this answer. Oh, and there is a missing comma

Comment: Oops my bad. And the question mentions editors and edits to books. Table 1 contains all the editors, and table 2 contains all the edits. All edits belong to an editor, thus a parent/child relationship is it not?

Comment: That I can buy into @DaveChen my bad

Answer (score -1):

Check this.

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.editorID
WHERE table1.ID = 2;
```