# how to Delete Record From join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to Delete Record from Two different Table but i join those table using Left join

```
DELETE tab_issue.tab_issueID, tab_return.tab_issueID
FROM tab_issue
INNER JOIN tab_return
WHERE tab_issue.tab_issueID = tab_return.tab_issueID
```

I have no strong concept on sQL 
if someone have simple query which solve my issue.
I am using mySQL database

Comment: Can you confirm whether it is a `left` or `inner` join?

Comment: You want to delete a tab_issue and its related tab_returns?

Comment: And which DBMS are you actually using? MySQL is not SQL Server, and SQLite is still another product. And what does all this have to do with PHP? Don't tag products and topics that are not involved. I've removed all these tags. Please tag only the DBMS you are using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql

Comment: in table where record display i used left join but here in query i use inner join for delete table...

Comment: You still haven't tagged your DBMS. Which is it? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? Which? And you haven't answered my question.

Comment: i tag dbms and i'm using mysql database

Comment: So you DBMS is MySQL. I've tagged it for you now.

Comment: And again: What do you want to delete exactly? Do you want to 
delete a particular tab_issue and its related tab_returns? Or what else?

Comment: tab_issue and tab_return are two tables in database and i use left join to join both and display in table now i want to know how to delete each record on click.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
DELETE tab_issue, tab_return
FROM tab_issue INNER JOIN tab_return
ON tab_issue.tab_issueID = tab_return.tab_issueID;
```

Comment: but i want to delete single record on click its delete whole data from table..???

Comment: This delete records of both tables, which have the same `tab_issueID` in both both tables.

Comment: I am afraid your question is not well understood. Maybe you can try to give an example of tables with data and what those tables might look like after the `delete` statement is executed ?