# MySQL Deleting related rows when they are not in another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with over a 100 users that never finished the signin process. I'm trying to delete those users **together with all data associated with them.**

Since the table relations were not added by the previous developer working on this, I have to do all queries manually.

I came up with the following right now

> The last of the 3 queries tries to delete all companies which don't have a company_id in the users table, so all companies that don't have a user associated with them.

The **locations** and **tags** constraint kick in, So I have to delete those first. That's how I built this query.. But it's a lot of code and it's hard to read. Any way to improve this?

```
delete from locations where company_id in (select id from companies 
where not exists (select null from users where users.company_id = 
companies.id));

delete from tags where company_id in (select id from companies where 
not exists (select null from users where users.company_id = 
companies.id));

delete from companies where not exists (select null from users where 
users.company_id = companies.id);
```

### What i've tried

- Using SET @todelete = (select...) : but it's throwing errors that my Subquery returns more than 1 record.

Am I doing this the right way? Or can it be simplified?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show table structure and maybe some sample data.  I can't figure out what you are trying to do from the queries alone.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>There's not much difference between your approach and mine. Please consider this just an attempt to make the solution readable</sub>

Since you are trying to delete those data from `location` \ `tags` \ `companies` tables having lonely `company_id`, first you need to find out which companies are lonely. The definition of lonely company is - *A company which don't have any adherence to any user is said to be lonely in this context*.

The following query provides `id` of those lonely companies:

```
SELECT 
    C.company_id
FROM companies C 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 
        1
        FROM users U 
        WHERE U.company_id = C.company_id
    );
```

---

Now you can delete data from `location` table associated to the lonely companies using the above helper query.

```
DELETE 
L
FROM locations L 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        C.company_id
    FROM companies C 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 
        1
        FROM users U 
        WHERE U.company_id = C.company_id
    )
) AS helper
ON L.company_id = helper.company_id;
```

In this approach you can delete data from other tables too.

See [**Delete with join in MySQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql/38939059#38939059)