# What's wrong with my DELETE query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've two tables with same columns. I'm trying to delete rows from table1 '600_LONDON_NUMBER' which are in table2 '600_LONDON_NUMBER1'. Below is my query but when I run it, MS Access says "**Could not delete from the specified Tables**". Please Help

```
DELETE [600_LONDON_NUMBER].*
FROM 600_LONDON_NUMBER INNER JOIN 600_LONDON_NUMBER1 
ON ([600_LONDON_NUMBER].GFCID = [600_LONDON_NUMBER1].GFCID) AND ([600_LONDON_NUMBER].CUSTBaseNO = [600_LONDON_NUMBER1].[CUST Base NO]);
```

P.S. When I run the `SELECT` Statement for the same query, it retrives the data without any Issue. I've also checked that data is not `readonly` I can delete using simple `DELETE`query.

Comment: And this is a MySQL database?

Comment: the part between `DELETE` and `FROM` is unnecessary

Comment: add a sub query in where clause to delete data

Comment: @FlorianKoch `MsAccess` can have that **part**. see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177896(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @FlorianKoch Tried removing it, now it says **"Specify the table containing the records you want to delete"**

Comment: sorry, i missed something, i changed the answer

Comment: @SankarRaj ok good to know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete with Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql)

Comment: Ok, that's what you get when you go rogue on the tags. Now you got a bunch of MySQL answers and comments that are useless to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `EXISTS` to solve it

```
DELETE 600_LONDON_NUMBER.* FROM 600_LONDON_NUMBER 
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM 600_LONDON_NUMBER1 
     WHERE [600_LONDON_NUMBER].GFCID = [600_LONDON_NUMBER1].GFCID) AND 
           [600_LONDON_NUMBER].CUSTBaseNO = [600_LONDON_NUMBER1].[CUSTBaseNO]
)
```

Comment: What's that 1 representing in SELECT 1?

Comment: `EXISTS` operator returns true, if `SELECT` return at least something, therefore, scalar value 1 is that something.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to add the correct column name... below works.. `DELETE 600_LONDON_NUMBER.* FROM 600_LONDON_NUMBER 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 600_LONDON_NUMBER1 WHERE [600_LONDON_NUMBER].GFCID = [600_LONDON_NUMBER1].GFCID AND 
           [600_LONDON_NUMBER].CUSTBaseNO = [600_LONDON_NUMBER1].[CUST Base NO]);`