# What's wrong in this statement? It is giving syntax error delete from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1. Id=t2.id where t2.id is null

Tags: mysql

What's wrong in this statement? It is giving syntax error in mysql

```
delete 
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1. Id=t2.id 
where t2.id is null
```

Please provide your suggestions

Comment: Does this help: [Delete with Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/652770/1048425)

Answer (score 1):

When joining you need to specify from which table(s) you want to delete

```
delete t1
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.id 
where t2.id is null
```