# How to delete all rows if ID not exist in same table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table in mysql like this:

| id | userID | idRef | userIDRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 30 | 6 | 100 |
| 5 | 30 | 7 | 100 |
| 7 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 30 | 8 | 100 |

In php I want to remove all rows for userID = 30 where userIDRef = 100 and idRef not exist in table. In this example I want to remove rows with idRef = 6 and idRef = 8 because not exist inside table

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE userID = 30
  AND idRef != 0
  AND idRef NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE userID = 100
    AND)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create test data:

```
DROP TABLE if EXISTS _tmpTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmpTable (
    id INT,
    userID INT,
    idRef INT,
    userIDRef INT
);
insert into _tmpTable VALUES
    (1, 30, 2, 100),
    (2, 100, 0,0),
    (3, 30, 6, 100),
    (5, 30, 7, 100),
    (7, 100, 0, 0),
    (10, 30, 8, 100)
;
SELECT * FROM _tmpTable
;
```

Now do the deletion:

```
DELETE FROM _tmpTable
WHERE 
        userID = 30
    AND UserIDRef = 100
    AND idRef NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM _tmpTable)
;
```

... and verify:

```
SELECT * FROM _tmpTable;
```

Comment: I get an error “ You can't specify target table '_tmpTable' for update in FROM clause”

Comment: @TheCesco1988 You're right, the statement above only works for MariaDB. For Mysql use the statement given by erik258

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
delete
from test  using test 
left join 
  (select distinct id from test)t2 
on test.idRef  =t2.id
  where test.userIdRef=100 and test.userID=30
      and  t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL You can [join in a delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql).

So you can do something like this:

```
delete t from t 
left join t t2 on (t.idRef = t2.id)
where t2.id is null and t.idRef > 0;
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/LOLHDzEp.  Thanks to Flingo64 for the table creates.